# Activity2 fixed when in background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a MainActivity inside it 4 Fragments, where in fragment 1 I call an activity

my problem:
If I open the Activity2 and exit the application left it in the background, when I come back in my app the MainActivy is active being that right and it remains in Activity2

How can I make it stay in Activity2?

sorry about my English ;)

my code

```
** protected void OnListViewItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(Activity2));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }**
```

Comment: Show some code of your MainActivity and Activity2.

Comment: `exit the application left it in the background`  how did you exit the application? kill the app at background task? or call `finish()`  function?

Comment: I did not close the application so I left it in the background